# MIL-STD-1750A to Decimal Conversion Examples

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-accuracy, floating-point-precision

I am looking at some examples in the [1750A format webpage](http://www.xgc.com/manuals/m1750-ada/m1750/c189.html#AEN322) and some of the examples do not really make sense. I have included the 1750A format specification at the bottom of this post in case anyone isn't familiar with it.

Take this example from Table 3 of the 1750A format webpage:

`.625x2^4 = 5000 00 04`

In binary `5000 00 04` is `0101 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100`

If you convert this to decimal, it does not equal 10, which is .625x2^4. Maybe I am converting it incorrectly.

Take the mantissa, `101 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000` and subtract 1 giving `100 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111`. Then flip the bits, giving `011 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`. Move the decimal 4 places (since our exponent, `0100` is 4), giving us `0110.0000 0000 0000 0000 000`. This equals 6.0, which is not .625x2^4.

I believe the actual value, should be `0011 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 01000` or `30000004` in hex.

Can anyone else confirm my suspicions that this value is labeled incorrectly in Table 3 of the 1750A format page above?

Thank you

[image: 1750A]

Comment: And what's the difference between this and your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562997/converting-ieee-754-float-to-mil-std-1750a-float)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Just another curious question regarding the examples listed on that website. Just looking for someone to help me understand them completely.

Comment: I don't understand why you're doing the conversion on the mantissa; it's already in the form you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [explained previously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14563481/129570), the sign+mantissa is interpreted as a 2's-complement value between -1 and +1.

In your case, it's 0.101000000... (base-2).  Which is 1/2 + 1/8 = 0.625 (base-10).

Answer (score 0):

It all makes perfect sense.

Here:

```
0101 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100
```

you've got:

(0*2<sup>0</sup> + 1*2<sup>-1</sup> + 0*2<sup>-2</sup> + 1*2<sup>-3</sup> + 0*2<sup>-4</sup> + ... + 0*2<sup>-23</sup>) * 2<sup>4</sup> = (0.5 + 0.125) * 16 = 0.625 * 16 = 10

Just do the math.